# layout-v4 and layout-v11? Should I duplicate files?

Tags: android, android-layout

I must create 2 folder `layout` and `layout-v11`. Inside, there is 5 files, but only one change.
Must I put all files in the folder, ore can just put in v11 the file who changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to put the files that are different.

You should have the `layout` folder (without any numbers) and put all the common files there. Only files that are different per version should go to folders with version numbers, e.g. `layout-v11`.

This way you don't need to have the same content in 2 places and it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I was checking it out ! It is better like that ! Tx for helping !